# Self-calling anonymous function without declaring as variable

Tags: php, recursion, anonymous-function, php-5.5

I want to call an anonymous function without declaring a variable for it.

**I know that this is a working example:**

```php
$foo = function ($bar) use ($foo) {
    if (is_array($bar)) {
        foreach ($bar AS $current) {
             $foo($current);
        }
    }
    else {
        print($bar);
    }
};

$foo($input);

# Unset variable cause we won't need it anymore
# and we like to have a lot of free memory.
unset($foo);
```

**But I want to call and unset it automatically:**

```php
call_user_func(function ($bar) {
    if (is_array($bar)) {
         foreach ($bar AS $current) {
             # This won't work
             # as our function doesn't have any name.
             call_user_func(__FUNCTION__, $current);
         }
    }
    else {
         print($bar);
    }
}, $input);
```

#### But this example won't work, because our function does not have a name. Is there any solution or do you know any solution to solve this problem?

---

PS: Let's suppose that `$input` is the following array: `["Hello, ", "World!"]`.

As of that, the output should be:

```php
Hello, 
World!
```

---

**Update #1:**

As this is just an example, `call_user_func_array(function () { ... }, $input)` is not the solution I am looking for.

And it wouldn't be working if I have an `$input` like `[["Hello, ", "World"], "!"]`.

---

**Update #2:**

Another solution I'm *not* looking for is `debug_backtrace()[1]['args'][0]->__invoke($current);`. I think it is ugly enough to use for *debug* only. :)
Thanks to [@fschmengler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/664108/fschmengler).

And the other form of this is `call_user_func(debug_backtrace()[1]['args'][0], $current));`.

---

**Update #3:**

Another solution written by [@UlrichEckhardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968182/ulrich-eckhardt) is embedding the anonymous function into another anonymous function. I think, unsetting the previously declared function variable - eg. first example - is both cleaner and shorter. But this is a solution too.

```php
function () {
    $f = function ($param) use ($f) {
        // use $f here
    }
    return $f;
}()
```

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski The `(function() {...})();` solution would be interesting, but not actual for now. Maybe the only available solution is making a `call_user_anonym_func()` for PHP 5.5 - 5.6. (?)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski The first example is a working one, so it does. But I don't want to declare a variable for the function and store it in it (or `unset()` if it finished.
(It doesn't really make sense, but is an interesting question, I think.)

Comment: Sorry, sorry. When I went off to search for related questions I forgot you said the top example works. I'll delete earlier comments.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski no problemo! :D

Comment: Before reinventing wheels, have you checked the `array_walk_recursive()`? It iterates a tree of nested arrays and calls a function on every leaf(!) element.

Comment: How can you say that unsetting a variable of an anonymous function frees a lot of memory? What if your foremost assumption just is wrong? AFAIK you can't unload class definitions that way in PHP.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to access the closure with `debug_backtrace()` and <del>use `__invoke()` to call it</del> call it with `call_user_func()` as before:

```
$input = ["Hello, ", "World!"];

call_user_func(function ($bar) {
    if (is_array($bar)) {
         foreach ($bar AS $current) {
             call_user_func(debug_backtrace()[1]['args'][0], $current));
         }
    }
    else {
         print($bar);
    }
}, $input);
```

But in my opinion, the first version where you assign the closure to a variable is more readable and I don't see any arguments against it, other than personal taste.

**Update:** it has to be `call_user_func()` again, not `__invoke()`, so that args[0] references the closure for every level of recursion

Comment: Yeah, this is a solution near to the one I'm looking for. But we should use it only for debug(`_backtrace ...`), so I won't mark it as the solution _I am looking for_.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Write a closure returning the closure you want and call that:

```
function () {
    $f = function ($param) use ($f) {
        // use $f here
    }
    return $f;
}()
```

I'm actually not convinced that PHP is capable of defining and calling a function in one step, you may have to use `call_user_func()` instead to work around your language's shortcomings here. That aside, there are much better ways to write obfuscated code and if that is surprisingly not your goal, there might even be clearer alternatives. ;-)

Comment: I wrote a helper function which works like this called `call_user_anonym_func()`. I'll post that asap. :)
Thanks!

Comment: Btw, this is just an interesting question for me. It has no goal other then getting to know alternative solutions. :)
(+ and choosing the best as answer if there is some)